# Read/write process memory in Julia

Tags: julia

Is there any possibility to read and write process memory in Julia? I give example in C# what I mean:

`WinAPI.ReadProcessMemory(c_Process.handle, offset, buffer, size, IntPtr.Zero);`

Comment: On Windows you could call that function directly. Use `GetModuleHandleEx` first. [Here](https://github.com/ihnorton/Win32GUIDemo.jl) are example winapi calls. Cross-platform, in-process could use `ccall(:jl_load_dynamic_library, ...)` for handle, and `reinterpret` +  [`unsafe_*`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/stdlib/c/#Base.unsafe_load) functions. If that hand-wavy description isn't enough, I'll try to come up with an example. (note: that's for same-process only, reading *other process* memory in a cross-platform way is more difficult I think. may be better to use shared memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an arbitrary pointer and read or write through it, but it's not recommended to program this way. Here's a short program to segfault Julia:

```
julia> p = reinterpret(Ptr{Int}, 0)
Ptr{Int64} @0x0000000000000000

julia> unsafe_store!(p, 123)

signal (11): Segmentation fault: 11
```